# Error in implementation o f junit through ant

Tags: ant, junit

While implementing junit through ant i get the following error

```
td/devenv/exceptions/EjbDelegateException"  type="java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError">java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: td/devenv/exceptions/EjbDelegateException
at td.soa.inventory.test.RemoteDokLink.testGetLayer2Ring(RemoteDokLink.java:483) Caused by:
  java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: td.devenv.exceptions.EjbDelegateException
  at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:202)
  at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
  at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:306)
  at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:301)
  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247)
```

The Junit code is given below the first part is the execution of junit

The second part is the junit definition where all the jars used in cide are explained

```
          <!--  Jenkins implementation  --> 
   <property name="dir.build.test.classes" location="${basedir}/build/classes/test" /> 
        <property name="dir.dist" location="${basedir}/build/dist" /> 
        <property name="dir.junit.rep" location="${basedir}/build/junitoutput" />  
        <property name="dir.build.classes" location="${basedir}/build/classes" /> 
        <property name="dir.src" location="${basedir}/src" />  
        <property name="dir.lib.jar" location="${basedir}/lib" />
        <property name="jar.junit" location="T:/External/JUnit/3.8.1/junit.jar" /> 
        <property name="jar.weblogic" location="T:/bea/wlserver_10.3/server/lib"/>
        <property name="jar.XMLBroker" location="T:/EAIUTIL/Xbroker"/>
        <property name="jar.apt-jelly" location="T:/External/apt-jelly/2.3"/>
        <property name="jar.DokLink" location="D:/junitttest/DokLink_WLS10/build/lib"/>
        <property name="jar.DokLink-client" location="D:/junitttest/DokLink_WLS10/build/lib"/>
```

Please can anyone help

Comment: Could you show the Ant target for the JUnit tests please.

Comment: i have give the ant target for junit below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like EjbDelegateException class is not available to the dependent class at runtime. Please check path in your build file.